# is it possible to export a (not reusable) list workflow to another site collection?

Tags: workflow

is it possible to export a (**not reusable**) list workflow to another site collection?

what are the limitations?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new workflow on your targeted list and add empty activity.  This will setup the XML in the XOML file.  You can then copy your XOML and Rules over.  You'll have to re-open your workflow in SPD, and go thru and click on all your data references so they are re-associated correctly.  If you have any lookup in your workflow, you need to either re-create them manually in SPD or update the XML with the correct GUID references.

In this case, there is no silver bullet.  A third party like Quest or AvePoint can help if you do this routinely.   I've done this in the past, and with complex Workflows, plan on spending some time troubleshooting.